# Radius of convergence for $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}(-z)^n$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

At first glance , I though that the series

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}(-z)^n$$

diverges, since the minus sign alternates by the value of the exponent. For odd-valued exponents, the partial sum is negative, and vice versa. So since the series appears as divergent, I would think that the radius of convergence is zero. But this does not seem to be the case.

If I want to calculate the radius of convergence for this series, I use the formula:
$$\frac{1}{R}=\mathop {\lim \sup }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } (|c_n|)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

for the sequence $(-z)^n$

$$R=\frac{1}{\mathop {\lim \sup }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } |(-z)|^{-\frac{1}{n}}}=\mathop {\lim \sup }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } (z)^{\frac{1}{n}}=1$$

So since this radius of convergence is correct, why does the sequence appear as a divergent series (by the alternating sign)?

Comment: You should read about Alternating Series Test: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series

Comment: " Like any series, an alternating series converges if and only if the associated sequence of partial sums converges. ". Have a look a this: https://www.math.tamu.edu/~tom.vogel/gallery/node9.html

Comment: That is not how you calculate the radius of convergence at all. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem#Theorem_for_one_complex_variable) for the correct expression.

Comment: Why does the series 'appears as divergent'?

Comment: The "things" that have a Radius of Convergence are Power Series $\sum a_n z^n$. So here we have $a_n=(-1)^n$. Now calculate the R of C correctly as @Gary says and get $R=1$. The series is convergent for $|z|<1$ and divergent for $|z|>1$. What's your problem?

Comment: "Like any series, an alternating series converges if and only if the associated sequence of partial sums converges." Then look at a few partial sums to get some intuition. Take, for instance, $z=\frac12$. What are the partial sums?$$1=1\\1-\frac12=\frac12\\1-\frac12+\frac14=\frac34\\1-\frac12+\frac14-\frac18=\frac58\\1-\frac12+\frac14-\frac18+\frac1{16}=\frac{11}{16}$$ Draw those points on the number line if you think that helps. Does it look convergent?

Comment: @Arthur yes! Thanks.   Gary, thanks for that note. I will revise.

Comment: Among the several points that are incorrect in your question (and that have been already mentionned by the other comments), I would like to notice this one : *since the series appears as divergent, I would think that the radius of convergence is infinite*. If really the series was divergent for all $z \neq 0$, then the radius would have been $0$ and not $\infty$.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe corrected!

Comment: @ViolaPlayer You are still not getting it. If you want to match your problem with the form $$
\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {c_n (z - a)^n } 
$$ given in the Wikipedia, what is $c_n$ and $a$ in your case?

Comment: How do you mean?

Comment: @ViolaPlayer Maybe writing $\sum (-1)^n z^n$ could help you understand what Gary means.

Comment: Thanks for the correction Gary. I see you emphasize also plus infinity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write your power series as
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {( - 1)^n z^n } .
$$
By the Cauchy–Hadamard formula the radius of convergence $R$ is
$$
R = \frac{1}{{\mathop {\lim \sup }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \left| {( - 1)^n } \right|^{1/n} }} = \frac{1}{{\mathop {\lim \sup }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } 1^{1/n} }} = \frac{1}{{\mathop {\lim \sup }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } 1}} = \frac{1}{1} = 1.
$$
Thus, the power series converges if $|z|<1$ and diverges if $|z|>1$.

Comment: Thanks, it is clear now!

Comment: I took your approach here and applied it on $\sum_{n=0}^\infty2\cdot z^n$ and as far as I can see from this, it gives $R=\frac{2}{\lim_{n\longrightarrow\infty}(|z|^n)^{1/n}}=\frac{2}{\lim_{n\longrightarrow\infty}(|z|)}=\frac{2}{z}$? It seems strange to me, as the solution should be 2

Comment: @ViolaPlayer I thought last time you finally understood what is going on. It seems you did not. You *do not* have $z$ in the computation of $R$!!! $$
R = \frac{1}{{\lim \sup \left| 2 \right|^{1/n} }} = \frac{1}{1} = 1.
$$ Look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem#Theorem_for_one_complex_variable) again. You have $c_n = 2$ for all $n$ and $a=0$ in your case. Now look at the formula for $1/R$ given in the link. It involves $c_n$ and not $z$. When looking at power series you care about what multiplies the power of $z$.

Comment: Indeed Gary! Thanks for this, this really makes this clear now, although it was already from your post. Sorry for being distracted! All the best

Comment: @ViolaPlayer Note also that $\sum\nolimits_{n = 0}^\infty  {2 \cdot z^n }  = 2 \cdot \sum\nolimits_{n = 0}^\infty  {z^n }$. So you can take $c_n=1$ as well, you get the same result.

Comment: Thanks again Gary. Does this mean that it is actually written $\sum_{n=0}^\infty2\cdot cz^n$, and that the formula for radius of convergence can be generalized to $A\sum_{n=0}^\infty cz^n$, accounting for other coefficients, where $c=\pm 1$ and A, in this case is 2?

Comment: If $A$ is a constant independent of $n$ and $z$, then $$
\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {A \cdot c_n (z - a)^n }  = A \cdot \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {c_n (z - a)^n } .
$$ The fact that the radius of convergence is the same follows also from the fact that $
\left| A \right|^{1/n}  \to 1$.

Comment: Great, understood. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This series converges in the region $\vert z\vert<1$. The region of convergence can be found by
$\vert\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}\vert<1$ for series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty u_n$.

Comment: What if $$
u_{2n}  = \frac{1}{{3^n }}z^{2n} ,\quad u_{2n + 1}  = \frac{1}{{2^n }}z^{2n+1} \;?
$$

Comment: @Gary....Then $R=min(R_1,R_2)$ where $R_1$ and $R_2$ are the radii of convergence of individual sub-series respectively.

Comment: I know how to do it. I just wanted to point out that your answer, as it stands, does not apply in general. The Cauchy–Hadamard formula works generally.

Comment: What if series is $\sum z^{n!}$?

Comment: $c_k=1$ if $k=n!$ for some $n\geq 0$ and $c_k=0$ otherwise. So $
\lim \sup \left| {c_k } \right|^{1/k}  = 1 \Rightarrow R = 1/1 = 1
$.

Comment: Thats my point. The exponent used in formula may be misleading sometimes.

Comment: Maybe if you are a beginner. Anyway, I do not think there is anything here to argue about. I made a valid point and that is it.